# Proving the completeness of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Here $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ denotes the vector space of all bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. We can define a norm on $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ by $\|T\| = \inf\{B : \|T(v)\| \leq B \|v\|\}$. Using this, we define a metric $d(T_1, T_2) = \|T_1 - T_2\|$. Under this metric, we wish to prove that $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ is complete.

Given a Cauchy sequence $\{T_i\}$ I defined $T(v) = \lim_{i\to\infty} T_i(v)$ (where the limit is obviously taken in $\mathcal{H}$). I have shown that $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$. How can I show that indeed $T_i \to T$ in $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$?

It should be noted that this question comes from Stein & Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*, Chapter 4, Exercise 18. I am not doing this problem for homework. Rather, I'm working the problems in preparation for my upcoming qualifying exam.

Comment: I changed \text{inf} to \inf and did some other emendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting your hands dirty!

Since for A and B being vector spaces normed: $\mathcal{L}(A;B)$ is Banach iff B is Banach, and $\mathcal{H}$ is Banach, then $\mathcal{L(H)}=\mathcal{L(H;H)}$ is Banach.

Comment: A Hilbert space is a _complete_ inner-product space. How about $\mathcal H$ is Banach _by definition_?

Comment: I don't know what "Space Reflexive" or "Banach" mean, nor have I seen a proof that $\mathcal{H}^{**} \simeq \mathcal{H}$. This seems like some high-level machinery for an exercise which is intended to get the user's hands dirty.

Comment: @triple_sec, fixed! 
I'm head in the clouds!

Comment: @AlexG., this is not necessary, since H is Banach.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio Could you provide a proof or link to a proof that $\mathcal{L}(A;B)$ is Banach iff $B$ is Banach?

Comment: @AlexG., Yes, you just need an implication, to see this: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section4d.pdf, Theorem C.26. I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio You have been, thank you!

Comment: @AlexG. You should've accepted the other answer, the one that actually has content. This one is of the "this is true because it's already known to be true" variety.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal L(\mathcal H,\mathcal H)$. For each $x\in\mathcal H$, $(T_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal H$, since for any $m,n\in\mathbb N$, $$\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|\leq\|T_n-T_m\|\|x\|.$$ Given that $\mathcal H$ is complete, $T(x)\equiv \lim_{n\to\infty} T_n(x)$ exists for each $x\in\mathcal H$. For any $x,y\in\mathcal H$ and $a,b\in\mathbb C$, $$T(ax+by)=\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n(ax+by)=a\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n(x)+b\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n(y)=aT(x)+bT(y),$$
so $T$ is a linear function.

Let $N\in\mathbb N$ be so large that $\|T_n-T_N\|<1$ for any $n\geq N$. Fix $x\in\mathcal H$, $x\neq0$, and let $n\in\mathbb N$ be so large that (i) $n\geq N$ and (ii) $\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|<\|x\|$, which is possible due to pointwise convergence and the assumption that $\|x\|>0$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\|T(x)\|\leq&\,\|T(x)-T_n(x)\|+\|T_n(x)-T_N(x)\|+\|T_N(x)\|\\
\leq&\,\|x\|+\|T_n-T_N\|\|x\|+\|T_N\|\|x\|\leq(2+\|T_N\|)\|x\|.
\end{align*}
Obviously, this inequality is still true for $x=0$. It follows that $\|T\|$ is bounded. (The crucial part was to make sure that $N$ did not depend on $x$.)

Finally, one can show that $T_n\to T$ in the operator norm. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Let $N\in\mathbb N$ be so large that $\|T_n-T_m\|<\varepsilon/2$ if $m,n\geq N$. Fix any $x\in\mathcal H$, $x\neq0$ and let $m\in\mathbb N$ so large that (i) $m\geq N$ and (ii) $\|T_m(x)-T(x)\|<\|x\|\varepsilon/2$. Then, if $n\geq N$, the following holds:
\begin{align*}
\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|\leq&\,\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|+\|T_m(x)-T(x)\|\leq\|T_n-T_m\|\|x\|+\frac{\|x\|\varepsilon}{2}\\
\leq&\,\frac{\|x\|\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\|x\|\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon\|x\|.
\end{align*}
This is true also if $x=0$. It follows that $\|T_n-T\|\leq\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$ (NB: $N$ does not depend on $x$), completing the proof.